# Deploy war file on tomcat using maven issue

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

Trying to deploy .war file in tomcat apache server using maven but its throwing an error.. Please find the below error: also please find the below POM.XML, Settings.XML and tomcat-uesrs.XML configured.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy
(default-cli) on project SampleMaven1: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Error writi
ng to server -> [Help 1]
```

Please find pom.xml configuration

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

      <groupId>SampleMaven</groupId>
      <artifactId>SampleMaven1</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <packaging>war</packaging>

      <name>SampleMaven1</name>
      <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

      <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
      </properties>

      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.42.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.8</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>

      <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>

            <configuration>
            <skipTests>false</skipTests>
            <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
            <forkMode>once</forkMode>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>   

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/html</url>
                <server>tomcatserver</server>                   
                <path>/SampleMaven1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war</path>
                <!-- <username>admin</username>
                <password>admin</password> -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>           
      </plugins>
      </build>
</project>
```

Tomcat-users.xml..

```
<role rolename="manager"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="admin"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="admin,manager,manager-gui"/>
```

and Maven settings.xml

```
<server>
   <id>TomcatServer</id>
   <username>admin</username>
   <password>admin</password>
</server>
```

tried giving the commands `cmd mvn tomcat:deploy` & `mvn tomcat7:deploy`

but getting the same error.. Any suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the manager URI in the plugin configuration.

The URI

```
http://localhost:8080/manager/html
```

points to the manager web interface but does not interprets server commands, the corretc manager endpoint URI should be

```
http://localhost:8080/manager/text
```

for Tomcat 7 or

```
http://localhost:8080/manager/
```

if you are on Tomcat 6.

More info at [Tomcat Manager HowTo](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html)